How to get frame's id in python?
I have the following function for frame detection:
import inspect


def quantum():
    quantum_frame = inspect.currentframe()
    quantum_frame_id = ...

how would I obtain the id of the frame?
tried:
quantum.id

as a result I get an AttributeError

Why do you think a frame should have an id? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects

it does,  because it shows on object-representation during debugging

Can you provide a sample of that?

You can check it yourself, the question is, for some reason closed.

How exactly would I check it? What are you using for debugging? We have no idea what you're looking at, please provide more details.

You can use the answer below to check it. It exactly provides, what I needed.

As AKX commented on that: the id() of an object doesn't mean very much. What are you hoping to do with that?

Does this help?
import inspect

def quantum():
    quantum_frame = inspect.currentframe()
    quantum_frame_id = id(quantum_frame)
    return quantum_frame_id

frame_id = quantum()
print("Frame ID:", frame_id)


That id() doesn't really mean much, though.
